# Route requests to IPs depending on the (sub)domain the server was accessed from

Tags: iptables, routing, redirect, xinetd, stream

Example:
1) The server is running **Ubuntu** and is on a LAN (192.168.9.*)
2) The server is running several services on local IPs (Eg: **192.168.9.5** VPS (OpenVZ))
3) A client connecting from **vps1.mydomain.com** will receive data from the **192.168.9.5** (Slightly similar to **Xinetd** but without listening on a certain port)
4) The client would be able to access all services that are hosted publicly on **192.168.9.5** (Apache, Squid, etc...)
5) **vps1.mydomain.com:3128** would allow you to connect to the Squid proxy server.
Is this possible?

Thanks! =)

Comment: I can't see the connection between the title and body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client is connecting from vps1.mydomain.com (as specified in example #3), then trying to connect to vps1.mydomain.com:3128 (example #5) will mean that they're connecting to the same machine (or NAT device) that they're coming from.

The only way to get around that is to implement some sort of proxy on the client machine or to implement some sort of IP rewriting that will forward vps1.mydomain.com:3128 over to 192.168.9.5:3128